# Tensorflow feed_dict adds extra dimension to variables?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, the final layer of my network looks like:

```
layer3output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer2output, weightsLayer3) + biasesLayer3)
```

If I check the size of the output:

```
print(tf.shape(layer4output))
```

I get:

```
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

I expected that `layer3output` is a 1D vector, but the above indicates 2D. Does the extra dimension correspond to examples fed via `feed_dict`?

If so, then do all Tensorflow variables have one extra dimension when feed_dict is used?

*UPDATE*:  Please see the code below. It prints out the 6x3 `weights` tensor and 1x3 `biases` tensors, and shows the `tf.shape` of these as `(2,)` and `(1,)` respectively. These have more than 2 and 1 elements, so do `(2,)` and `(1,)` really mean the number of elements? They do however correspond to the number of dimensions. ...?

```
import tensorflow as tf
nInputs = 6
nUnitsLayer1 = 3
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([nInputs, nUnitsLayer1]))
biases= tf.Variable(tf.zeros(nUnitsLayer1))

print 'nInputs', nInputs
print 'nUnitsLayer1', nUnitsLayer1
print 'weights shape', tf.shape(weights)
print 'biases shape', tf.shape(biases)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print 'weights'
    print (weights.eval())
    print 'biases'
    print (biases.eval())
```

*OUTPUT:*

```
nInputs 6
nUnitsLayer1 3
weights shape Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
biases shape Tensor("Shape_1:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
weights
[[ 0.16274141 -0.20140187  0.05342311]
 [ 0.06554962  0.97961253  0.48603743]
 [-0.49525094 -0.85534018 -0.49244919]
 [ 0.09299681 -1.76659465 -0.64823383]
 [ 0.98095983  1.53840697  0.55010611]
 [-0.99781513 -1.18230617  0.22286507]]
biases
[ 0.  0.  0.]
```

Comment: `shape=(2,)` means it's a 1d vector with 2 elements

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav. But now I am even more confused. Can you please see the example code above? It seems that the actual tensor dimensions do not match the results from `tf.shape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; you need to `print sess.run(tf.shape` rather than `print tf.shape`

There's a difference between an "abstract" tensor and it's a actual value. For instance, `tf.shape(x)` is an "abstract" Tensor that represents shape of `x`. If `x` has rank two, then `tf.shape` will be a 1-D Tensor with 2 elements. This information is obtained during graph construction time using static shape inference, which you can see by using `.get_shape()` method on a Tensor. It seems `__str__` method of Tensor also uses information from static shape inference, which is what you see when you print it. To get the actual value of a tensor, you need to put it through `sess.run`